# How to count words before or after semicolon

Tags: python

```
countLeft=0
countRight=0
for line in open("jane_eyre_sentences.txt"):
  line_strip = line.rstrip();
  splitWord = line_strip.split(";");
  leftWord=splitWord[0].split();
  rightWord=splitWord[1].split();
  for word in leftWord:
    countLeft+=1

  for word in rightWord:
    countRight+=1
```

Example:
-----"What does Bessie say I have done?" I asked.
-----"Jane, I don't like cavillers or questioners; besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.
-----Be seated somewhere; and until you can speak pleasantly, remain silent."

There is one semicolon in each sentences at most.My question is that some sentences don't contain semicolon, so rightWord=Word[1].split() will out of range. How to do that?

Comment: Post your code, not screenshot of your code

Comment: Can you also share some example input data?

Comment: It seems like you want to get lengths of sentences between semicolons?

Comment: Is *Jane, I don't like cavillers or questioners; besides, there is something truly forbidding in a child taking up her elders in that manner.* one single sentence?

Comment: Yes,that is one sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, split the string with semicolon as the separator.

split_string would be a list. Now check for length. If the length is 1, it the string did not have a semicolon. If the length is 2, then it had one semicolon. (I do not know whether you have a scenario where there would be more than one semicolon as it is not mentioned in the question).

After checking the length, you can count the words with a split.

**Full Example Code:**

```
split_string = some_string.split(";")

if not split_string:
    left_words = 0
    right_words = 0
elif len(split_string) > 1:
    left_words = len(split_string[0].split())
    right_words = len(split_string[1].split())
else:
    left_words = len(split_string[0].split())
    right_words = 0

print "Left words: ", left_words
print "Right words: ", right_words
```

If **some_string** is *"this is a string with a ; semicolon", the output is:

```
Left words:  6
Right words:  1
```

And if **some_string** is *"this is a string without a semicolon", the output is:

```
Left words:  7
Right words:  0
```

Cheers.